# Dúvidas com Mapeamento XML

Tags: c#, xml, desserialização, xmldocument

Tenho um arquivo `XML` conforme abaixo e tenho algumas dúvidas em relação à como mapeá-lo para fazer a desserialização. Estou utilizando `C#`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ListaDeclaracoes>
    <declaracaoImportacao>
        <adicao>
            <acrescimo>
                <codigoAcrescimo>16</codigoAcrescimo>
                <denominacao>CARGA, DESCARGA E MANUSEIO NA ENTRADA - PAIS DE IMPORTACAO  </denominacao>
                <moedaNegociadaCodigo>790</moedaNegociadaCodigo>
                <moedaNegociadaNome>REAL/BRASIL</moedaNegociadaNome>
                <valorMoedaNegociada>000000000009041</valorMoedaNegociada>
                <valorReais>000000000009041</valorReais>
            </acrescimo>
            <acrescimo>
                <codigoAcrescimo>9 </codigoAcrescimo>
                <denominacao>VALOR DE QUALQUER PARCELA                                   </denominacao>
                <moedaNegociadaCodigo>220</moedaNegociadaCodigo>
                <moedaNegociadaNome>DOLAR DOS EUA</moedaNegociadaNome>
                <valorMoedaNegociada>000000000002898</valorMoedaNegociada>
                <valorReais>000000000009455</valorReais>
            </acrescimo>
            <cideValorAliquotaEspecifica>00000000000</cideValorAliquotaEspecifica>
            <cideValorDevido>000000000000000</cideValorDevido>
            <cideValorRecolher>000000000000000</cideValorRecolher>
            <codigoRelacaoCompradorVendedor>1</codigoRelacaoCompradorVendedor>
            <codigoVinculoCompradorVendedor>1</codigoVinculoCompradorVendedor>
            <cofinsAliquotaAdValorem>01065</cofinsAliquotaAdValorem>
            <cofinsAliquotaEspecificaQuantidadeUnidade>000000000</cofinsAliquotaEspecificaQuantidadeUnidade>
            <cofinsAliquotaEspecificaValor>0000000000</cofinsAliquotaEspecificaValor>
            <cofinsAliquotaReduzida>00000</cofinsAliquotaReduzida>
            <cofinsAliquotaValorDevido>000000000132712</cofinsAliquotaValorDevido>
            <cofinsAliquotaValorRecolher>000000000132712</cofinsAliquotaValorRecolher>
            <condicaoVendaIncoterm>FOB</condicaoVendaIncoterm>
            <condicaoVendaLocal>SHANGHAI</condicaoVendaLocal>
            <condicaoVendaMetodoValoracaoCodigo>01</condicaoVendaMetodoValoracaoCodigo>
            <condicaoVendaMetodoValoracaoNome>METODO 1 - ART. 1 DO ACORDO (DECRETO 92930/86)</condicaoVendaMetodoValoracaoNome>
            <condicaoVendaMoedaCodigo>220</condicaoVendaMoedaCodigo>
            <condicaoVendaMoedaNome>DOLAR DOS EUA</condicaoVendaMoedaNome>
            <condicaoVendaValorMoeda>000000000367200</condicaoVendaValorMoeda>
            <condicaoVendaValorReais>000000001198136</condicaoVendaValorReais>
            <dadosCambiaisCoberturaCambialCodigo>4</dadosCambiaisCoberturaCambialCodigo>
            <dadosCambiaisCoberturaCambialNome>SEM COBERTURA CAMBIAL</dadosCambiaisCoberturaCambialNome>
            <dadosCambiaisInstituicaoFinanciadoraCodigo>00</dadosCambiaisInstituicaoFinanciadoraCodigo>
            <dadosCambiaisInstituicaoFinanciadoraNome>N/I</dadosCambiaisInstituicaoFinanciadoraNome>
            <dadosCambiaisMotivoSemCoberturaCodigo>52</dadosCambiaisMotivoSemCoberturaCodigo>
            <dadosCambiaisMotivoSemCoberturaNome>ADMISSAO EM REGIME ADUANEIRO ESPECIAL OU ATIPICO</dadosCambiaisMotivoSemCoberturaNome>
            <dadosCambiaisValorRealCambio>000000000000000</dadosCambiaisValorRealCambio>
            <dadosCargaPaisProcedenciaCodigo>000</dadosCargaPaisProcedenciaCodigo>
            <dadosCargaUrfEntradaCodigo>0000000</dadosCargaUrfEntradaCodigo>
            <dadosCargaViaTransporteCodigo>00</dadosCargaViaTransporteCodigo>
            <dadosMercadoriaAplicacao>REVENDA</dadosMercadoriaAplicacao>
            <dadosMercadoriaCodigoNaladiNCCA>0000000</dadosMercadoriaCodigoNaladiNCCA>
            <dadosMercadoriaCodigoNaladiSH>00000000</dadosMercadoriaCodigoNaladiSH>
            <dadosMercadoriaCodigoNcm>61161000</dadosMercadoriaCodigoNcm>
            <dadosMercadoriaCondicao>NOVA</dadosMercadoriaCondicao>
            <dadosMercadoriaMedidaEstatisticaQuantidade>00001224000000</dadosMercadoriaMedidaEstatisticaQuantidade>
            <dadosMercadoriaMedidaEstatisticaUnidade>PARES</dadosMercadoriaMedidaEstatisticaUnidade>
            <dadosMercadoriaNomeNcm>- Impregnadas, revestidas ou recobertas, de plástico ou</dadosMercadoriaNomeNcm>
            <dadosMercadoriaPesoLiquido>000000057630000</dadosMercadoriaPesoLiquido>
            <dcrCoeficienteReducao>00000</dcrCoeficienteReducao>
            <dcrIdentificacao>00000000</dcrIdentificacao>
            <dcrValorDevido>000000000000000</dcrValorDevido>
            <dcrValorDolar>000000000000000</dcrValorDolar>
            <dcrValorReal>000000000000000</dcrValorReal>
            <dcrValorRecolher>000000000000000</dcrValorRecolher>
            <documentoVinculado>
                <codigoTipo>2</codigoTipo>
                <nomeTipo>DI</nomeTipo>
                <numero>1705949748     </numero>
            </documentoVinculado>
            <fornecedorCidade>SHANGHAI</fornecedorCidade>
            <fornecedorComplemento>SHANGHAI SHANGHAI</fornecedorComplemento>
            <fornecedorEstado>SHANGHAI</fornecedorEstado>
            <fornecedorLogradouro>ENDERECO FORNECEDOR</fornecedorLogradouro>
            <fornecedorNome>SHANGHAI LIMITED</fornecedorNome>
            <fornecedorNumero>9855</fornecedorNumero>
            <freteMoedaNegociadaCodigo>000</freteMoedaNegociadaCodigo>
            <freteValorMoedaNegociada>000000000009041</freteValorMoedaNegociada>
            <freteValorReais>000000000029499</freteValorReais>
            <iiAcordoTarifarioTipoCodigo>0</iiAcordoTarifarioTipoCodigo>
            <iiAliquotaAcordo>00000</iiAliquotaAcordo>
            <iiAliquotaAdValorem>03500</iiAliquotaAdValorem>
            <iiAliquotaPercentualReducao>00000</iiAliquotaPercentualReducao>
            <iiAliquotaReduzida>00000</iiAliquotaReduzida>
            <iiAliquotaValorCalculado>000000000436145</iiAliquotaValorCalculado>
            <iiAliquotaValorDevido>000000000436145</iiAliquotaValorDevido>
            <iiAliquotaValorRecolher>000000000436145</iiAliquotaValorRecolher>
            <iiAliquotaValorReduzido>000000000000000</iiAliquotaValorReduzido>
            <iiBaseCalculo>000000001246133</iiBaseCalculo>
            <iiFundamentoLegalCodigo>00</iiFundamentoLegalCodigo>
            <iiMotivoAdmissaoTemporariaCodigo>00</iiMotivoAdmissaoTemporariaCodigo>
            <iiRegimeTributacaoCodigo>1</iiRegimeTributacaoCodigo>
            <iiRegimeTributacaoNome>RECOLHIMENTO INTEGRAL</iiRegimeTributacaoNome>
            <ipiAliquotaAdValorem>00000</ipiAliquotaAdValorem>
            <ipiAliquotaEspecificaCapacidadeRecipciente>00000</ipiAliquotaEspecificaCapacidadeRecipciente>
            <ipiAliquotaEspecificaQuantidadeUnidadeMedida>000000000</ipiAliquotaEspecificaQuantidadeUnidadeMedida>
            <ipiAliquotaEspecificaTipoRecipienteCodigo>00</ipiAliquotaEspecificaTipoRecipienteCodigo>
            <ipiAliquotaEspecificaValorUnidadeMedida>0000000000</ipiAliquotaEspecificaValorUnidadeMedida>
            <ipiAliquotaNotaComplementarTIPI>00</ipiAliquotaNotaComplementarTIPI>
            <ipiAliquotaReduzida>00000</ipiAliquotaReduzida>
            <ipiAliquotaValorDevido>000000000000000</ipiAliquotaValorDevido>
            <ipiAliquotaValorRecolher>000000000000000</ipiAliquotaValorRecolher>
            <ipiRegimeTributacaoCodigo>4</ipiRegimeTributacaoCodigo>
            <ipiRegimeTributacaoNome>SEM BENEFICIO</ipiRegimeTributacaoNome>
            <mercadoria>
                <descricaoMercadoria>CÓD: 2.042.017.003 - LUVA DE SEGURANÇA, RE. 1676BB, CONFECCIONADA EM FIOS DE FIBRA SINTÉTICA, COM REVESTIMENTO EM RESINA NITRÍLICA NA PALMA, FACE PALMAR E PONTA DOS DEDOS, PUNHO TRICOTADO COM ELASTANO, ACABAMENTO FINAL EM OVERLOQUE. TAMANHO YELING 9 (G)</descricaoMercadoria>
                <numeroSequencialItem>01</numeroSequencialItem>
                <quantidade>00001224000000</quantidade>
                <unidadeMedida>PARES               </unidadeMedida>
                <valorUnitario>00000000000004500000</valorUnitario>
            </mercadoria>
            <nomenclaturaValorAduaneiro>
                <atributo>AB</atributo>
                <especificacao>0002</especificacao>
                <nivelNome>SUBITEM             </nivelNome>
            </nomenclaturaValorAduaneiro>
            <nomenclaturaValorAduaneiro>
                <atributo>AA</atributo>
                <especificacao>0001</especificacao>
                <nivelNome>SUBITEM             </nivelNome>
            </nomenclaturaValorAduaneiro>
            <numeroAdicao>001</numeroAdicao>
            <numeroDI>1708600000</numeroDI>
            <numeroLI>0000000000</numeroLI>
            <paisAquisicaoMercadoriaCodigo>160</paisAquisicaoMercadoriaCodigo>
            <paisAquisicaoMercadoriaNome>CHINA, REPUBLICA POPULAR</paisAquisicaoMercadoriaNome>
            <paisOrigemMercadoriaCodigo>160</paisOrigemMercadoriaCodigo>
            <paisOrigemMercadoriaNome>CHINA, REPUBLICA POPULAR</paisOrigemMercadoriaNome>
            <pisCofinsBaseCalculoAliquotaICMS>00000</pisCofinsBaseCalculoAliquotaICMS>
            <pisCofinsBaseCalculoFundamentoLegalCodigo>00</pisCofinsBaseCalculoFundamentoLegalCodigo>
            <pisCofinsBaseCalculoPercentualReducao>00000</pisCofinsBaseCalculoPercentualReducao>
            <pisCofinsBaseCalculoValor>000000001246133</pisCofinsBaseCalculoValor>
            <pisCofinsFundamentoLegalReducaoCodigo>00</pisCofinsFundamentoLegalReducaoCodigo>
            <pisCofinsRegimeTributacaoCodigo>1</pisCofinsRegimeTributacaoCodigo>
            <pisCofinsRegimeTributacaoNome>RECOLHIMENTO INTEGRAL</pisCofinsRegimeTributacaoNome>
            <pisPasepAliquotaAdValorem>00210</pisPasepAliquotaAdValorem>
            <pisPasepAliquotaEspecificaQuantidadeUnidade>000000000</pisPasepAliquotaEspecificaQuantidadeUnidade>
            <pisPasepAliquotaEspecificaValor>0000000000</pisPasepAliquotaEspecificaValor>
            <pisPasepAliquotaReduzida>00000</pisPasepAliquotaReduzida>
            <pisPasepAliquotaValorDevido>000000000026168</pisPasepAliquotaValorDevido>
            <pisPasepAliquotaValorRecolher>000000000026168</pisPasepAliquotaValorRecolher>
            <relacaoCompradorVendedor>Fabricante é o Exportador</relacaoCompradorVendedor>
            <seguroMoedaNegociadaCodigo>000</seguroMoedaNegociadaCodigo>
            <seguroValorMoedaNegociada>000000000000000</seguroValorMoedaNegociada>
            <seguroValorReais>000000000000000</seguroValorReais>
            <sequencialRetificacao>00</sequencialRetificacao>
            <valorMultaARecolher>000000000000000</valorMultaARecolher>
            <valorMultaARecolherAjustado>000000000000000</valorMultaARecolherAjustado>
            <valorReaisFreteInternacional>000000000029499</valorReaisFreteInternacional>
            <valorReaisSeguroInternacional>000000000000000</valorReaisSeguroInternacional>
            <valorTotalCondicaoVenda>36720000000</valorTotalCondicaoVenda>
            <vinculoCompradorVendedor>Não há vinculação entre comprador e vendedor.</vinculoCompradorVendedor>
        </adicao>
        <armazem>
            <nomeArmazem>LOGISTICA  </nomeArmazem>
        </armazem>
        <armazenamentoRecintoAduaneiroCodigo>9999999</armazenamentoRecintoAduaneiroCodigo>
        <armazenamentoRecintoAduaneiroNome>CLIA PARANA LTDA</armazenamentoRecintoAduaneiroNome>
        <armazenamentoSetor>015</armazenamentoSetor>
        <canalSelecaoParametrizada>003</canalSelecaoParametrizada>
        <caracterizacaoOperacaoCodigoTipo>1</caracterizacaoOperacaoCodigoTipo>
        <caracterizacaoOperacaoDescricaoTipo>Importação Própria</caracterizacaoOperacaoDescricaoTipo>
        <cargaNumeroAgente>N/I</cargaNumeroAgente>
        <cargaPaisProcedenciaCodigo>160</cargaPaisProcedenciaCodigo>
        <cargaPaisProcedenciaNome>CHINA, REPUBLICA POPULAR</cargaPaisProcedenciaNome>
        <cargaPesoBruto>000000062730000</cargaPesoBruto>
        <cargaPesoLiquido>000000057630000</cargaPesoLiquido>
        <cargaUrfEntradaCodigo>0917800</cargaUrfEntradaCodigo>
        <cargaUrfEntradaNome>PORTO DE PARANAGUA</cargaUrfEntradaNome>
        <conhecimentoCargaId>CEMERCANTE99999999</conhecimentoCargaId>
        <conhecimentoCargaIdMaster>999999999999999</conhecimentoCargaIdMaster>
        <conhecimentoCargaTipoCodigo>12</conhecimentoCargaTipoCodigo>
        <conhecimentoCargaTipoNome>HBL - House Bill of Lading</conhecimentoCargaTipoNome>
        <conhecimentoCargaUtilizacao>2</conhecimentoCargaUtilizacao>
        <conhecimentoCargaUtilizacaoNome>Parcial</conhecimentoCargaUtilizacaoNome>
        <dataDesembaraco>20170607</dataDesembaraco>
        <dataRegistro>20170526</dataRegistro>
        <documentoChegadaCargaCodigoTipo>3</documentoChegadaCargaCodigoTipo>
        <documentoChegadaCargaNome>DTA</documentoChegadaCargaNome>
        <documentoChegadaCargaNumero>16/99999999</documentoChegadaCargaNumero>
        <documentoInstrucaoDespacho>
            <codigoTipoDocumentoDespacho>01</codigoTipoDocumentoDespacho>
            <nomeDocumentoDespacho>FATURA COMERCIAL                                            </nomeDocumentoDespacho>
            <numeroDocumentoDespacho>16FC9999999C             </numeroDocumentoDespacho>
        </documentoInstrucaoDespacho>
        <documentoInstrucaoDespacho>
            <codigoTipoDocumentoDespacho>29</codigoTipoDocumentoDespacho>
            <nomeDocumentoDespacho>ROMANEIO DE CARGA                                           </nomeDocumentoDespacho>
            <numeroDocumentoDespacho>S/NR                     </numeroDocumentoDespacho>
        </documentoInstrucaoDespacho>
        <documentoInstrucaoDespacho>
            <codigoTipoDocumentoDespacho>28</codigoTipoDocumentoDespacho>
            <nomeDocumentoDespacho>CONHECIMENTO DE CARGA                                       </nomeDocumentoDespacho>
            <numeroDocumentoDespacho>TANU999999999            </numeroDocumentoDespacho>
        </documentoInstrucaoDespacho>
        <dossie>
            <dossieDataVinculacao>29052017</dossieDataVinculacao>
            <dossieHoraVinculacao>101438</dossieHoraVinculacao>
            <dossieNumero>201799999999999</dossieNumero>
            <indicadorDossieVazio>N</indicadorDossieVazio>
        </dossie>
        <embalagem>
            <codigoTipoEmbalagem>99</codigoTipoEmbalagem>
            <nomeEmbalagem>OUTROS                                                      </nomeEmbalagem>
            <quantidadeVolume>00051</quantidadeVolume>
        </embalagem>
        <freteCollect>000000000000000</freteCollect>
        <freteEmTerritorioNacional>000000000000000</freteEmTerritorioNacional>
        <freteMoedaNegociadaCodigo>220</freteMoedaNegociadaCodigo>
        <freteMoedaNegociadaNome>DOLAR DOS EUA</freteMoedaNegociadaNome>
        <fretePrepaid>000000000009041</fretePrepaid>
        <freteTotalDolares>000000000009041</freteTotalDolares>
        <freteTotalMoeda>9041</freteTotalMoeda>
        <freteTotalReais>000000000029499</freteTotalReais>
        <icms>
            <agenciaIcms>99999</agenciaIcms>
            <bancoIcms>999</bancoIcms>
            <codigoTipoRecolhimentoIcms>2</codigoTipoRecolhimentoIcms>
            <cpfResponsavelRegistro>99999999999</cpfResponsavelRegistro>
            <dataPagamentoIcms>20170608</dataPagamentoIcms>
            <dataRegistro>20170608</dataRegistro>
            <horaRegistro>151636</horaRegistro>
            <nomeTipoRecolhimentoIcms>Recolhimento Bancário Mediante Documento de Arrecadação</nomeTipoRecolhimentoIcms>
            <numeroSequencialIcms>001</numeroSequencialIcms>
            <ufIcms>PR</ufIcms>
            <valorTotalIcms>000000000138762</valorTotalIcms>
        </icms>
        <importadorCodigoTipo>1</importadorCodigoTipo>
        <importadorCpfRepresentanteLegal>99999999999</importadorCpfRepresentanteLegal>
        <importadorEnderecoBairro>BAIRRO</importadorEnderecoBairro>
        <importadorEnderecoCep>99999999</importadorEnderecoCep>
        <importadorEnderecoComplemento>COMPLEMENTO</importadorEnderecoComplemento>
        <importadorEnderecoLogradouro>LOGRADOURO</importadorEnderecoLogradouro>
        <importadorEnderecoMunicipio>MUNICIPIO</importadorEnderecoMunicipio>
        <importadorEnderecoNumero>9999</importadorEnderecoNumero>
        <importadorEnderecoUf>PR</importadorEnderecoUf>
        <importadorNome>LUVAS LUVAS LUVAS</importadorNome>
        <importadorNomeRepresentanteLegal>REPRESENTANTE</importadorNomeRepresentanteLegal>
        <importadorNumero>99999999999999</importadorNumero>
        <importadorNumeroTelefone>99  99999999</importadorNumeroTelefone>
        <informacaoComplementar>INFORMAÇÃO COMPLEMENTAR</informacaoComplementar>
        <localDescargaTotalDolares>000000000381909</localDescargaTotalDolares>
        <localDescargaTotalReais>000000001246131</localDescargaTotalReais>
        <localEmbarqueTotalDolares>000000000372868</localEmbarqueTotalDolares>
        <localEmbarqueTotalReais>000000001216634</localEmbarqueTotalReais>
        <numeroDI>1799999999</numeroDI>
        <operacaoFundap>N</operacaoFundap>
        <pagamento>
            <agenciaPagamento>9999 </agenciaPagamento>
            <bancoPagamento>341</bancoPagamento>
            <codigoReceita>0086</codigoReceita>
            <codigoTipoPagamento>1</codigoTipoPagamento>
            <contaPagamento>             999999</contaPagamento>
            <dataPagamento>20170526</dataPagamento>
            <nomeTipoPagamento>Débito em Conta</nomeTipoPagamento>
            <numeroRetificacao>00</numeroRetificacao>
            <valorJurosEncargos>000000000</valorJurosEncargos>
            <valorMulta>000000000</valorMulta>
            <valorReceita>000000000436147</valorReceita>
        </pagamento>
        <pagamento>
            <agenciaPagamento>9999 </agenciaPagamento>
            <bancoPagamento>341</bancoPagamento>
            <codigoReceita>7811</codigoReceita>
            <codigoTipoPagamento>1</codigoTipoPagamento>
            <contaPagamento>             999999</contaPagamento>
            <dataPagamento>20170526</dataPagamento>
            <nomeTipoPagamento>Débito em Conta</nomeTipoPagamento>
            <numeroRetificacao>00</numeroRetificacao>
            <valorJurosEncargos>000000000</valorJurosEncargos>
            <valorMulta>000000000</valorMulta>
            <valorReceita>000000000021450</valorReceita>
        </pagamento>
        <pagamento>
            <agenciaPagamento>9999 </agenciaPagamento>
            <bancoPagamento>341</bancoPagamento>
            <codigoReceita>5602</codigoReceita>
            <codigoTipoPagamento>1</codigoTipoPagamento>
            <contaPagamento>             999999</contaPagamento>
            <dataPagamento>20170526</dataPagamento>
            <nomeTipoPagamento>Débito em Conta</nomeTipoPagamento>
            <numeroRetificacao>00</numeroRetificacao>
            <valorJurosEncargos>000000000</valorJurosEncargos>
            <valorMulta>000000000</valorMulta>
            <valorReceita>000000000026169</valorReceita>
        </pagamento>
        <pagamento>
            <agenciaPagamento>9999 </agenciaPagamento>
            <bancoPagamento>341</bancoPagamento>
            <codigoReceita>5629</codigoReceita>
            <codigoTipoPagamento>1</codigoTipoPagamento>
            <contaPagamento>             999999</contaPagamento>
            <dataPagamento>20170526</dataPagamento>
            <nomeTipoPagamento>Débito em Conta</nomeTipoPagamento>
            <numeroRetificacao>00</numeroRetificacao>
            <valorJurosEncargos>000000000</valorJurosEncargos>
            <valorMulta>000000000</valorMulta>
            <valorReceita>000000000132713</valorReceita>
        </pagamento>
        <seguroMoedaNegociadaCodigo>000</seguroMoedaNegociadaCodigo>
        <seguroTotalDolares>000000000000000</seguroTotalDolares>
        <seguroTotalMoedaNegociada>000000000000000</seguroTotalMoedaNegociada>
        <seguroTotalReais>000000000000000</seguroTotalReais>
        <sequencialRetificacao>00</sequencialRetificacao>
        <situacaoEntregaCarga>ENTREGA CONDICIONADA A APRESENTACAO E RETENCAO DOS SEGUINTES DOCUMENTOS: COMPROVANTE DE LIBERACAO DO AFRMM DOCUMENTO DE ARRECADACAO DO ICMS</situacaoEntregaCarga>
        <tipoDeclaracaoCodigo>14</tipoDeclaracaoCodigo>
        <tipoDeclaracaoNome>NACIONALIZACAO DE ENTREPOSTO ADUANEIRO</tipoDeclaracaoNome>
        <totalAdicoes>001</totalAdicoes>
        <urfDespachoCodigo>0915200</urfDespachoCodigo>
        <urfDespachoNome>CURITIBA</urfDespachoNome>
        <valorTotalMultaARecolherAjustado>000000000000000</valorTotalMultaARecolherAjustado>
        <viaTransporteCodigo>01</viaTransporteCodigo>
        <viaTransporteMultimodal>N</viaTransporteMultimodal>
        <viaTransporteNome>MARíTIMA</viaTransporteNome>
        <viaTransporteNomeTransportador>HAPAG-LLOYD AKTIENGESELLSCHATT</viaTransporteNomeTransportador>
        <viaTransportePaisTransportadorCodigo>023</viaTransportePaisTransportadorCodigo>
        <viaTransportePaisTransportadorNome>ALEMANHA</viaTransportePaisTransportadorNome>
    </declaracaoImportacao>
</ListaDeclaracoes>
```

O documento pode conter várias seções de `adicao` por exemplo, porém ela não está contida dentro de uma seção `adicoes`, está diretamente na raiz. Este comportamento repete-se com as demais seções que possuem nós filhos.

A parte inicial eu mapeei da seguinte forma:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ListaDeclaracoes")]
public class ListaDeclaracoes
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "declaracaoImportacao")]
    public List<DeclaracaoImportacao> DIs { get; set; }
}
```

Mapear os elementos normais não é problema, porém não sei como mapear as seções descritas acima.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "declaracaoImportacao")]
public class DeclaracaoImportacao
{
    ///????
    public List<Adicao> Adicoes { get; set; }

    ///...
}
```

Antes de fazer a pergunta pesquisei no `google`, no `SOEN` e no `SOPT` e não encontrei nada que me ajudasse nessa questão.

Caso restem dúvidas sobre a questão, favor comentar para que eu possa complementá-la.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução para o mapeamento encontrada foi a seguinte:

```
public class DeclaracaoImportacao
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "adicao", Type = typeof(Adicao))]
    public List<Adicao> Adicoes { get; set; }

    ///...
}
```

Foi criada uma propriedade do tipo `List<>`, mas também poderia ser um `Array`, e dito que o elemento era adição e o próprio desserializador se encarrega do resto.